# Способы ускорить перемещение курсора pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui, mouse-event, uiautomation

У `pyautogui.moveTo()` скорость перемещения курсора примерно 100 пикселей в секунду. Мне надо 800-1000. Как сделать курсор быстрее? Если `pyautogui` не может этого, то, возможно, существуют другие библиотеки, которые это могут? Язык программирования не принципиален.

Comment: Нужно передать третий аргумент: pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, 2) - переместит курсор из текущей позиции в точку с координатами (100, 100) за 2 секунды

Comment: вы уверены, что дело не в `pyautogui.PAUSE`? (так как без третьего аргумента `moveTo(x,y)` мгновенно выполняется).

Answer (score 1):

Надо установить глобальную переменную `pyautogui.PAUSE:float` - задержка в секундах между операциями (например 0.01) или совсем отключить задержку `pyautogui.moveTo(x,y,_pause=False)`.